# Structuring many screens in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

When developing an Android UI for an application, and that UI has many screens (several master lists, several detail lists per kind, etc) then what's the "native" option to support all this?

Do I create a container that contains many fragments, and show only one fragment at a time?
Or do I create a new activity per fragment type?

As an example of what I'm talking about, consider the Twitter Android app. It has four main "master" screens (tabs at the top) that you swipe between. Selecting any item on any of these screens goes to some kind of detail item on a sub-screen, with a different type depending on what was selected.

How is a master screen like this laid out? Is it a single activity? Is there a convenient "view switcher" layout container to implement something like the Twitter top-level swipe-able tab view? Can I turn such a view into a fragment to use for detail presentation as well?

Here's a screen shot of the "main page" of the Twitter app. Swiping left/right switches between the "tabs" at the top. Clicking an element opens detail views, that may be recursive instances of this design.
http://cdn.thenextweb.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2013/04/Screenshot_2013-04-03-11-55-07.png

Comment: To clarify: At a high level, my question is: "Should I use many views and swap them in-and-out in a container, or should I use many Activities and switch back-and-forth between them?"
A secondary question is "is it possible to switch to a new activity using a scrolling/sliding animation?"

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen the Twitter app but it seems like the app has used the design pattern called Navigation Drawer described in the below link.

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It unfortunately doesn't address the actual question, though. The Twitter app looks nothing like Navigation Drawer apps.
I added a clarification to the question.